# Varnish: Backend with multiple IPs (or use somthing else)

Tags: caching, proxy, varnish, squid, varnish-vcl

I'm developing a system that connects to an external backend service (purchased from another company) where the system will exceed the monthly request quota by a lot. I'm trying to create a proxy/cache that will cache the requests and use the cached response if it's present.

**Use cases:**

***Case 1:***

1. User requests endpoint
2. Proxy doesn't have it cached
3. Proxy forwards request to external backend
4. Proxy caches response
5. Proxy returns response to user

***Case 2:***

1. User requests endpoint
2. Proxy has it cached
3. Proxy returns cached response

***Case 3:***

1. External backend sends webhook saying things were updated
2. Proxy clears cache

**Requirements:**

- Proxy needs to be able to cache files (mostly images)
- Three different URL:s that needs to be reached: url1.external-backend.com, url2.external-backend.com and url3.external-backend.com
- Preferably only one proxy for all three URL:s
- The three URL:s might have different paths (url1.external-backend.com/this/is/a/path) and also maybe queries (url1.external-backend.com?query=something)
- Would be nice if the proxy could be cleared based on what is sent from the external backend, but it's not necessary

**Thoughts so far:**

I have looked at two different systems for this so far, Varnish (https://varnish-cache.org/) and Squid (http://www.squid-cache.org/). I tried with Squid but I did not understand at all how to set up the config to work like above. The sample config file was really messy and impossible to understand, and I could not find any guide online for it.

I looked into Varnish and as far as I can see it might be possible to use. But I have a problem here.

**Problem:**

In Varnish's `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` there is the possibility to add backends, so I added the following:

```
backend page2 {
    .host = "url2.external-backend.com";
    .port = "443";
}
```

This gives something similar to this (I don't remember exactly and I can't see the error message right now):

```
Backend host "url2.external-backend.com": resolves to multiple IPv4 addresses.
Only one address is allowed.
Please specify which exact address you want to use, we found these:
        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I don't dare putting one of the IP:s instead of the hostname, and I'm not sure creating a director is the correct way. The reason for this is that I'm not in control over the hostname and they cannot guarantee that the IP-adresses will not change.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to make this work somehow in Varnish?
2. Can someone explain exactly how Squids config should look to work like the use cases and requirements above (if possible)?
3. Is there any other caching proxy service out there that might work better than Varnish or Squid?

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 can be done without problems. For round robin DNS based backends (same name gives different IPs per request) you should look at directors that has specific support for round robin: https://www.varnish-software.com/wiki/content/tutorials/varnish/multiple_varnishes.html#

3 can also be done. For instance by a HTTP PURGE request. Just make sure you whitelist what IPs ca so this. https://www.varnish-software.com/wiki/content/tutorials/varnish/vcl_examples.html#

Comment: The problem is, if I understand correctly, that I need to specifically state the different IP addresses in the round robin DNS, or am I wrong?

As I wrote, I'm not in control over the hostname and they cannot guarantee that the IP-adresses will not change.And I don't want to have to keep track of when they change the IP-adresses. The system is kind of business critical som I can't really afford it to go down because of this.

Comment: @BluePrint No, using directors you should be able to specify names even if those resolv to different ip-addresses per request.

Comment: Aha, so basically I put the URL and not the IP:s in the director server host?

Comment: Thats how I understand it. Havent workes worh directors myself though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe vmod-goto is what you are looking for: https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/goto/

It is not open source, but it solves exactly your problem.